# From numerical Number to a scientific format on a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of Pressions under oceans that look like this:

```
|   Pressure     |
 -------------
  0.0151

  0.00843

  0.00629

  0.00538
```

i want to write those float on Pascal with unit (PA) .

Comment: what is the data type of your data? is it list or dataframe?

Comment: Why not call the columns Pressure(Pa)?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar i have a dataframe , and the data points are floats  ,the disired output is something in this format :  6.14E-3 , i don't know actually how to do so ,

Comment: @SaraStone Please provide an input and a desired output for that input.  Currently your question is to broad to give you an answer.

Comment: what i actually have is numerical values on a column of my dataframe and i want to transform it into a scientific value